# How can I sort an array by the sum of child arrays js

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have this:

```
0 : [dns: 29, connect: 3, send: 0, wait: 183, receive: 0]
1 : [dns: 143, connect: 8, send: 0, wait: 791, receive: 1416]
2 : [dns: 143, connect: 23, send: 0, wait: 910, receive: 3741]
3 : [dns: 142, connect: 7, send: 0, wait: 785, receive: 823]
4 : [dns: 143, connect: 25, send: 0, wait: 925, receive: 3741, …]
5 : [dns: 159, connect: 40, ssl: 47, send: 0, wait: 940, …]
6 : [dns: 159, connect: 40, send: 0, wait: 962, receive: 3742]
```

I want this array to be sorted by the sum of dns, connect, send, wait, receive

Comment: Please add the code, not image and also show us what you've tried.

Comment: `I_have_this.sort((a,b)=>Object.values(a).reduce((a,b)=>a+b)-Object.values(b).reduce((a,b)=>a+b));`

Comment: Sorry of being not clear with the question, Ill edit it

Comment: [ {} ] you mean???

Comment: You might have to use the `sort` function

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1129270/1151408

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Array`'s `sort()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), eg

```
myArray.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a['dns']+ a['connect'] + .. - b['dns']- b['connect'] + ..;
});
```

Comment: way of accessing element from object is choice.

Comment: This is what I need, let me try

Answer (score 0):

Ok, with the help of you guys, I managed to do it, was easy :D

```
            function compare(a,b) {

             var sumA = a.connect + a.dns + a.receive + a.send + a.wait;
             var sumB = b.connect + b.dns + b.receive + b.send + b.wait;

             if (sumA < sumB)
                return 1;
             if (sumA > sumB)
                return -1;
             return 0;

            }

           arr.sort(compare);
```

Thank you!